# What verb form can be used after wish/hope?

Tags: verbs, tenses, backshifting

I understand that there is a backshift occuring with "wish" - I wish you were here (now). I wish I had tried (yesterday).

What if we are referencing to the future? Can there ever be "will" after wish?: I wish Santa will bring me gifts tomorrow. / I wish Santa brings me gifts tomorrow.

Furthermore, is the backshift dependent on the situation being perceived as unrealistic by the speaker? Compare: I wish Santa brings me gifts tomorrow. / I wish the war ended tomorrow.

And would this sentence be grammatical? I wish that you be here.

With "hope", I understand it we do not backshift. Here, the, in certain cases seemingly arbitrary, decision to use will vs. present tense confuses me. Compare: I hope I see you at the party tomorrow. / I hope I will see you at the party tomorrow. Is there a reason for both being viable? Is there maybe a difference in meaning between those two that I am not seeing?

I know that this is more than one question, but they seem somewhat related.

Comment: All your proposed versions are ungrammatical: *I wish Santa ❌brings me gifts tomorrow; I wish the war ❌ended tomorrow;  I wish that you ❌be here.* The duplicate I linked to contains examples of what is and is not possible.